# Canonical arrow between $\varinjlim _C \varprojlim _D F(C,D)\rightarrow \varprojlim_D \varinjlim _CF(C,D)$ in $\mathsf{Set}$

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading Borceux's *Handbook of Categorical Algebra, vol I*, section 2.13 on filtered colimits. The author starts by constructing a canonical map
$$\varinjlim _C \varprojlim _D F(C,D)\rightarrow \varprojlim_D \varinjlim _CF(C,D)$$
using universal properties. I understand this part.

Then, at the very beginning of the proof of the fact finite limits commute with filtered colimits in $\mathsf{Set}$, he claims that using the descriptions of limits and filtered colimits in $\mathsf{Set}$, the canonical arrow $\lambda$ is given by
$$\lambda ([(x_D)_{D\in \sf D}])=([x_D])_{D\in \mathsf D}  ,\;\;\;x_D\in F(C,D)$$

I do not understand - *why* must this be how $\lambda$ is defined in this case?

---

As the comments suggest, I will post my attempt. The definition of $\lambda$ is as follows. Denote by $(p_D)$ the universal cone of $\varprojlim _DF(C,D)$ and by $(s_C)$ the universal cocone of $\varinjlim _C F(C,D)$.

We start from the cocone
$$(\lambda_D)_C=s_C\circ p_D$$
to obtain via the isomorphism
$$\mathsf{Hom}(\varinjlim_C \varprojlim _D F(-,D),\varinjlim _CF(C,D))\cong \mathsf{Nat}(\varprojlim _D F(-,D),\varDelta \varinjlim _CF(C,D))$$
an arrow (for each $D\in \mathsf D$)
$$\lambda _D:\varinjlim _C\varprojlim _D F(C,D)\rightarrow \varinjlim _CF(C,D)$$

Now the isomorphism above is given by
$$f\leftrightarrow \varDelta (f)\circ s$$
where $s$ is the universal cocone as before. I don't understand how to continue from here. I don't see how $(\lambda_D)_C$ are of this form...

Comment: Have you tried to follow the general construction of the canonical map in this special case?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg $\lambda$ was constructed indirectly using the isomorphisms $\mathsf{Hom}(A,\varprojlim F)\cong \mathsf{Nat}(\varDelta A ,F)$ and $\mathsf{Hom}(\varinjlim F,A)\cong \mathsf{Nat}(F,\varDelta A)$, so I'm not sure how to find $\lambda$ itself...

Comment: Keep unwinding the definitions!

Comment: @ZhenLin I filled in details to the point at which I'm stuck.

Comment: There is a problem with your notation – $s$ and $p$ both depend on both $C$ and $D$.

Comment: @ZhenLin I'm just following Borceux.

Comment: Then maybe you should think about it more carefully.

Comment: @ZhenLin I thought about it and got stuck. That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Let me be more explicit: you should change your notation. That might alleviate some confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You may be trying to be a bit too formal. Here's how I'd explain it.

$\lambda$ is a map out of a colimit, so it's got components $\lambda_C$ for every $C$. $\lambda_C$ is a map into a limit, so it's got components $\lambda_C^D$ for every $D$. $\lambda_C^D:\varprojlim_D F(C,D)\to \varinjlim_C F(C,D)$ is given by projecting to $F(C,D)$ from the limit then mapping $F(C,D)$ to the colimit.

Now if $F$ is set-valued, trace the previous paragraph through: start with an equivalence class $[(x_D)]$ with a representative $(x_D)\in \varprojlim_D F(C,D)$, then map into the limit by, for each $D$, projecting to $x_D$ and including to the colimit. That's the description Borceux suggests.